# Show Curated List of Fonts in Fonts Selection Dropdown for PowerPoint Application

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint

We use just few curated list of Fonts family for our PowerPoint Presentations. But since their names are all over the place (due to alphabetic order), when I am selecting different fonts, it is always tedious work to select from Fonts dropdown list. Also, now Office 365 even shows more fonts that can be "downloaded", thus increasing the list even more.

**Is there a way to show only Curated list of fonts in the Dropdown, or any other way to create a custom dropdown list with few fonts?** I am asking this for PowerPoint, but this would be useful for MS Word as well.

I am aware that I can create PowerPoint template with specific fonts, but if you work in any team, you will know that not everyone uses the template correctly, thus creating this fonts soup in presentation.

[image: Curated List of Fonts in PowerPoint]

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know, the fonts list is untouchable.

Comment: Is there a macro or something that can do this?

Comment: @harrymc is correct: there's no way to customize the existing font dropdown. But by using RibbonXML in an add-in, you could add e.g. a new tab with your own font dropdown and possibly other tools specific to your branding.  I have an article here with some of the basics and references to more detailed info about RibbonXML:  https://www.rdpslides.com/pptfaq/FAQ01216-Create-an-ADD-IN-with-Ribbon-buttons-that-run-macros-when-clicked.htm

Comment: In any case, the fonts list starts with the most-recently-used fonts, so that modifying the list might not be needed.

Comment: @harrymc, the most-recently-used-fonts feature is flaky. Sometimes, when I open Fonts dropdown, it goes all the way down where the font is listed based upon the font name. Then if I select the font, it would put it in the recently used fonts at the top, but then again it may go down if some other fonts are used. Sorry for a confusing comment. But it is kind of frustrating experience. I may try SteveRindsberg suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg, I followed the steps in the link you sent. I was able to add a new ribbonUI item. Do you know where the RibbonUI Reference Material would be for different PowerPoint object/command/buttons (whatever it is called)? I am thinking of creating a custom font list dropdown, if at all is possible. Thanks a lot. This is incredible.

Comment: There are a couple of links to the MS RibbonX reference material at the bottom of the link I included above.